# Closure in the Space of Probability Measures with the Prohorov metric

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory

I have seen this result stated countless times: assume the metric space $(\theta,d)$ is separable; then $(\theta,d)$ is complete if and only if the space $(\mathcal{P}(\Theta),\rho)$ (the space of probability measures, taken with the Prohorov metric--which is equivalent to the weak* topology) is complete.  See, for instance,

- Billingsley, Convergence of Probability Measures (1968), pg 240
- W. Whitt, Weak Convergence of Probability Measures on the Function Space $C[0,\infty)$, Annals of Math. Stat 41 (1970), Corollary 2
- http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~vangaans/jancol1.pdf , Theorem 9.2

But if this result holds (say, for $\Theta = \mathbb{R}$), then $(\mathcal{P}(\Theta),\rho)$ is weak* closed, which is false (see, e.g., milanmerkle.com/documents/radovi/WEACO2a.pdf , Section 5.4; a similar discussion has been had on these boards: [Is the set of all probability measures weak*-closed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157795/is-the-set-of-all-probability-measures-weak-closed))

The proof of the first result typically relies on Prohorov's Theorem: take a Cauchy sequence $\{P_{n}\}$, show that the sequence is tight, therefore it is relatively sequentially compact.  But in all the cases mentioned above, the authors use *relative* sequential compactness to conclude that the sequence must have a convergent subsequence in the space of probability measures (rather than the closure of that space).  This seems to be the error, but the result is stated so ubiquitously that I feel I may be missing something....

UPDATE: I have located another related question: [Tightness of a sequence of probability measures and weak convergence of a subsequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50306/tightness-of-a-sequence-of-probability-measures-and-weak-convergence-of-a-subseq) 
In Billingsley's proof (of my result), we take a Cauchy sequence $\{P_{n}\}$ and show that the sequence is tight, which is taken to prove the convergence of a subsequence.  But this result seems incorrect, since tightness is only sufficient to prove the *relative* compactness of the set of measures in the sequence (by Prohorov's Theorem).

Comment: Why "if the result holds, then $(\cal P(\Theta),\rho)$ is weak$^*$ closed"?

Comment: If $(\mathcal{P}(\Theta),\rho)$ is weak* complete, then it must be weak* closed

Comment: You mean the weak star topology of which set?

Comment: I think this may be very closely related to the problem I am having...  It is trivial that $(\mathcal{P}(\Theta),\rho)$ is weak* closed in $(\mathcal{P}(\Theta),\rho)$ (in the subspace topology).  But perhaps $(\mathcal{P}(\Theta),\rho)$ is not weak* closed in the larger space of measures?  It seems possible that this may explain the divergent results obtained above, but it is not clear (to me).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is basically that on the space of probability measures, the topology induced by the Prohorov metric is not always the weak* topology. Basically, referring to convergence in the Prohorov metric as "weak convergence" of probability measures is somewhat unfortunate in this sense. If this claim is true, your example of $\Theta = \mathbb{R}$ does not yield a contradiction after all.

To put this into perspective, note the following. Let $C_b(\Theta)$ denote the set of bounded continuous functions on $\Theta$. Define $T_f:\mathcal{P}(\Theta)\to\mathbb{R}$ by $T_f(\mu) = \int f \; d\mu$. Two definitions:

1. A sequence of of probability measures $(\mu_n)$ converges to $\mu$ in the Prohorov metric if and only if $T_f(\mu_n)$ converges to $T_f(\mu)$ for all $f\in C_b(\Theta)$.
2. When $\mathcal{P}(\Theta)$ is a subset of the dual of $C_b(\Theta)$, a sequence of probability measures $(\mu_n)$ converges to $\mu$ in the weak* topology if and only if $T_f(\mu_n)$ converges to $T_f(\mu)$ for all $f\in C_b(\Theta)$.

So, when $\mathcal{P}(\Theta)$ is a subset of the dual of $C_b(\Theta)$, convergence in the Prohorov metric and weak* convergence are the same. However, this is not always the case.

If $(\Theta,d)$ is compact, it holds that $C(\Theta) = C_c(\Theta) = C_b(\Theta)$, i.e. the spaces of continuous functions, continuous functions with compact support and bounded continuous functions are the same, and furthermore, $C(\Theta)' = rca(\Theta)$, where $rca(\Theta)$ is the set of regular Borel measures on $(\Theta,d)$, and so $\mathcal{P}(\Theta)\subseteq rca(\Theta) = C_b(\Theta)$. Thus, in this case, convergence in the Prohorov metric and weak* convergence is the same. However, when $(\Theta,d)$ is not compact, the duality relationships do not always hold. I don't really have a counterexample at hand, but I'm confident that you can find one somewhere.

The above is basically one of the good reasons for having a theory of "weak convergence" for probability measures which is not just a reference to weak* convergence. For probability theory, our main interest is measures which are not supported on compact sets, and therefore we need a convergence theory which holds for such measures. The Prohorov metric and the associated convergence concept based on $C_b(\Theta)$ turns out to be a good solution.